# Struts CSS/Images per language

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, struts, struts-1

I have a web application deployed inJava using Struts 1 as the the MVC library.
I am required to provide different CSS/Images folders based on the selected language.
I already have WebMessageResources.properties configured with 4 different languages.

One approach I took is to define to the root path of the CSS/Images folder in the message resources.
However, I'm finding this to be somehow "dirty" and requiring changes all over the code.

For example, in one my JSP pages, I was forced get the path using JSP tags than concatenate the string in the css href.

> MessageResources mres =
>   MessageResources.getMessageResources(Constants.RESOURCES_BUNDLE);
>   Locale locale = (Locale)
>   pageContext.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY); String
>   langResources = mres.getMessage(locale, "path.resources");

....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= langResources %>css/styles.css" />
```

Is there a better "out of the box" way to do this? I'm not very familiar with Struts.

Answer (score 0):

struts has inbuild support for i18n. See this

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/

http://exadel.com/tutorial/struts/5.2/strutstutorials-i18n.html

Comment: I'm aware that Struts supports that. I am already using that, but I need to see what is the best way to provide different resource folders (Images/CSS) for different languages.